# Using ActiveMQ with more than one consumer instance

Tags: java, activemq-classic

In our architecture we've 2 or more containers for each application for
high availiability puproses.
We're using activeMQ and I would like to implement the following behavior.

1. Pushing to a message to queue.
2. This message will be consumed only by *one *container (the first one
   that will read it).
3. Once message processed successfully the consumer will update this
   message can be acknowledged and neglected
4. I tried using transaction with commit and using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE however
   in both cases both consumers got the message and processed it.

I want only one consumer to process each message based on availability.
Our implementation is in Java.

Please share the way to implement it.

Here is my code sample

```
 final Connection consumerConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    consumerConnection.start();
    // Create a session.
    final Session consumerSession = consumerConnection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    final Destination consumerDestination = consumerSession.createQueue(queueName);


    // Create a message consumer from the session to the queue.
    final MessageConsumer consumer = consumerSession.createConsumer(consumerDestination);
    // Begin to wait for messages.
    Queue queue = consumerSession.createQueue(queueName);
    QueueBrowser queueBrowser = consumerSession.createBrowser(queue);
    Enumeration msgs = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
    while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
        //do your things here

        ActiveMQTextMessage message = (ActiveMQTextMessage) msgs.nextElement();

        if (message == null)
            continue;

        //handle message
        System.out.println("Message received in : " + message);
        try {
            String text = message.getText();
            JSONObject messageJson = new JSONObject(text);
            consumer.receive(1000);

            String responseString = handleMessage(messageJson);

            message.acknowledge();
```

Thank you
Moshe

Comment: Assuming you're actually using a queue (and not a topic) and also assuming you're acknowledging the message appropriately (and not cancelling it back to the queue so it's available to another consumer) then everything should work as expected. Can you confirm both of these assumptions? Can you share your client code where you're creating the session and acknowledging the message?

Comment: Thnks @JustinBertram I updated question with my code

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're acknowledging the message from the `QueueBrowser` instance which will have no impact since browsers are only for browsing messages and not consuming them.

```
...
QueueBrowser queueBrowser = consumerSession.createBrowser(queue);
Enumeration msgs = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
    ...
    ActiveMQTextMessage message = (ActiveMQTextMessage) msgs.nextElement();
    ...
    try {
        ...
        message.acknowledge(); // this does nothing
```

You *are* actually creating a real consuming and calling `consumer.receive(1000)`, but you're discarding the `Message` instance the `receive()` returns.  This is the `Message` instance which you must acknowledge to actually consume the message from the queue.

```
...
// Create a message consumer from the session to the queue.
final MessageConsumer consumer = consumerSession.createConsumer(consumerDestination);
...
while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
    ...
    try {
        ...
        Message actualMessage = consumer.receive(1000); // acknowledge this!
        ...
```

Another important note...The messages which a queue browser receives are not guaranteed to be a static snapshot of the queue.  Therefore it's dangerous to assume that your call to `consumer.receive(1000)` is actually the *same* message which came from the queue browser. In my opinion you should rework this logic to work only with a `MessageConsumer` and drop the `QueueBrowser`.

Comment: Thank you but with this approach the moment I'm doing consumer.recieve the message is no longer at the queue. Which mean that if i fail in sending it to the next step it'll lost. How i can add commit level to this scenario so only after sending it to next step it'll be removed from queue.

Comment: Since you're using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode then the message should *not* be removed when `consumer.receive(1000)` returns as the JMS specification indicates.  You have to explicitly acknowledge either the message it returns or a message returned later in the same session.  If the message is being acknowledged then that's a bug in ActiveMQ. However, I doubt there's a bug as it would have been discovered by the project's automated unit tests.  I would encourage you to investigate this thoroughly to ensure this is happening as you suggest. Out of curiosity, what version of ActiveMQ are you using?